# Is every continuous complex function differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know every complex differentiable function is continuous. I would like to know if the converse is true. If not, could someone give me some counterexamples?

**Remark:** I know this is not true for the real functions (e.g. $f(x)=|x|$ is a continuous function in $\mathbb R$ which is not differentiable at the origin).

Answer (score 10):

No, for example, any non constant function s.t. for all $z$ you have $f(z)\in \mathbb R$. As you mentioned, $$f(z)=|z|$$
is a good counter-example. But a beautiful property, is that any complex differentiable function are infinitely differentiable.

Answer (score 4):

No, of course not. Complex differentiability is a very stringent property.

For examples, just look at any pair of continuous but not (real) analytic functions $a,b:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $F= a+ib$.

Answer (score 1):

Another classical family of  $\mathbb{C}$-continuous but not $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable functions: functions whose expression is analytic but involve a conjugation:

$f$ defined by $f(z):=\bar z sin(z)+cos(\bar z)$ is one of these.

Comment: I really like these, really nice class of examples

Answer (score 1):

A classic example is $f(z)=\bar{z}$. It is continuous everywhere but there is no open disk in which it is holomorphic, and therefore it is nowhere holomorphic.